# How to use pitch pipe app in different majors for singing?

Tags: voice

I have an app that can tell what what pitch I am singing but I have to give it a note such as C4. I know the notes/octaves in C major but I don't know what E4 would be in B flat major. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Music SE. Could you please reformulate your question and specify the exact question more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E4 is the major 3rd in C. So in Bb the major 3rd would be D.

All you have to do is to transpose the interval to the key you are requesting. Bb is 2 semitones lower than C so the tone you are looking for is also 2 semi tones lower than E: this is D.